# Can't complete a SMART test on FreeNAS

Tags: smart, freenas, zfs

I'm trying to run a disk test with `smartctl -t long` on FreeNAS.

But the test immediately aborts with `Aborted by host`.

From what I've read, this is because the system is using the drive, so it cannot continue to test.

How can I allow the test to finish? Unmount the volume? Use `captive` mode?

Answer (score 1):

The answer was patience ... the following morning, all the SMART tests completed. Apparently they get scheduled and eventually do complete, perhaps when disk activity is down.